# precommit hook failed [code 225] mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

I'm trying to commit with tortoiseHq, but I'm getting the error
`Abort: precommit.whitelist hook failed`, and the file is right since I diff'd with the file from another repo which is working fine and they have equal binary.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precommit hook is set only on your repo, and may not be on every repository just yet. That may explain why you have the same identical file elsewhere. Or maybe it existed before the hook was added.

Nonetheless, for the problem at hand, you have few options. Either contact your admin to see why the file is not on the `whitelist`, and add it to the list, or disable the hook on your repo. If you do the latter, you may still get rejected at the push, if the same hook is present there, too.

Comment: I got it fixed by contacting the admin. Thanks.